# How will I parse a tag with space in its value using antlr?

Tags: java, clojure, antlr, antlr4, ebnf

I have the following grammer.

```
meta 
    : '<' NAME '>' TEXT '</' NAME '>'
    | '<' NAME S* attribute* '>';

dl : '<' NAME '><' TEXT '>' dt* '</' NAME '><' TEXT '>';

dt : '<' NAME '><' NAME S* attribute* S* '>' TEXT '</' NAME '>';

attribute : attributeName '=' attributeValue;

attributeName : NAME;

attributeValue : VAL;

NAME : [A-Z0-9_-]+;

VAL : '"'.*?'"';

TEXT : [A-Za-z0-9:\/\.@\-;\s*]+;

S : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

The string is

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Abcd</TITLE>
<H1>Abcd</H1>
<DL><p>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1481473849" LAST_MODIFIED="1481473992" PERSONAL_XYZ_FOLDER="true">Foo bar</H3>
</DL><p>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ParseError extraneous input 'bar' expecting '</'  clj-antlr.common/parse-error (common.clj:146)
```

The problem is that the space is skipped so when `Foo bar` has a space it is giving an error. But if I am not skipping the space I get another error in the `META` parsing. (The `S*` is not required when skipping spaces).

```
ParseError extraneous input ' ' expecting {'>', NAME}
mismatched input '>' expecting '><'
mismatched input '<' expecting {<EOF>, COMMENT, S}  clj-antlr.common/parse-error (common.clj:146)
```

Here is my tokens file generated by antlr:

```
T__0=1
T__1=2
T__2=3
T__3=4
T__4=5
DTD=6
COMMENT=7
NAME=8
VAL=9
TEXT=10
S=11
'<'=1
'>'=2
'</'=3
'><'=4
'='=5
```

And when I run using `grun` I get the following, but I don't see any errors in the token reported. It is similar to the grammar I defined. How can I accept spaces in tag values?

```
$ grun MyGrammer r -tokens
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
[@0,0:0='<',<1>,1:0]
[@1,1:4='META',<8>,1:1]
[@2,5:5=' ',<11>,1:5]
[@3,6:15='HTTP-EQUIV',<8>,1:6]
[@4,16:16='=',<5>,1:16]
[@5,17:30='"Content-Type"',<9>,1:17]
[@6,31:31=' ',<11>,1:31]
[@7,32:38='CONTENT',<8>,1:32]
[@8,39:39='=',<5>,1:39]
[@9,40:65='"text/html; charset=UTF-8"',<9>,1:40]
[@10,66:66='>',<2>,1:66]
[@11,67:67='\n',<11>,1:67]
[@12,68:67='<EOF>',<-1>,2:0]
No method for rule r or it has arguments
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you skip a token, like S, then you can't use it in rules, the token won't be anywhere in the token stream for the parser to match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a space between `foo` and `bar` the lexer produces it as  two Tokens (of type `TEXT`) but the grammar states that only one name token is allowed. To solve your problem you simply have to allow a few TEXTs in a seqnece via the plus-operator:

```
dt : '<' NAME '><' NAME S* attribute* S* '>' TEXT+ '</' NAME '>';
```

Also notice that you might run into problems as the Lexer will convert quite a few inputs in NAMEs and not in TEXTs as they both can match the pattern `[A-Z0-9]+`

Comment: I gave `TEXT+` but I am getting an error: `ParseError extraneous input '  ' expecting {'</', TEXT}`

Comment: Like you said, when I give `BOO` as the tag value, it is matched by `NAME` so I am getting an error. How can I avoid that? I do not want to replace `NAME` with `TEXT` so that it does not match extra chars. Is it possible with antlr?

Comment: I fixed the last part giving `content` as the value and `content: NAME* | TEXT*;`. But space issue is not fixed.

Comment: Raven: Thank you very much! It worked. I was trying it without the `skip` part in `S`.

Comment: You're welcome! :) As you have already (partly)  found out that your problem in the lexer can be resolved by matching both needed Tokens as the same one in the layer and then define parser rules that combine the respective tokens from the lexer into a "new type"